# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to open csv file from google drive but this error occur.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4fHz.png)

I just want to open my data file in colab.

Comment: Have you tried printing `os.listdir` and see if you are one the right Path?

Comment: 1. Check you have mounted drive. 2. Check file path (give full path)

Answer (score 2):

Your colab can't recognize the path, you should follow these next steps:
1- be sure that you connected your colab to your drive through this block of code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2- after running the code above, you will see a pop-up window
[image: popupwindow]
You need to sign in to your google account to link your google drive with colab

3- Then, you can press on *copy path* and past it to the `read_csv` pandas' function
[image: Copy path]

Comment: I could not find the path from google drive. This above options are not appearing in my file. Please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried to run the code block above?
If so, next step you need is to sign in to your google account to connect your colab with your google drive, then you will see these folders and in addition, you will see the folders and files on your google drive on the side bar on the left side.

Comment: I edited my answer above and showed an example of the pop-up window that shows when you run the code block provided above.